# Communications link failure on datagrip

Tags: mysql, datagrip

We're runing on an issue with Datagrip and mysql (mariadb). Each time we execute a long query it stops at 50 seconds with an error but if we make a "show processlist" the query keeps on background and finish.

We tried running the query on another system (pentaho) and it keeps more than 50 seconds and finish. Is there any parameter to configure or so?

The error we get is the following:

```
[2021-10-28 10:57:57] [08S01] Communications link failure
[2021-10-28 10:57:57] The last packet successfully received from the server was 50.057 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 50.057 milliseconds ago.
[2021-10-28 10:57:57] java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
```

Comment: please try this - open up data source properties, go to Advanced tab and set 0 for all options with 'timeout' in name. which drier do you use to connect - is it native MariaDB?

Comment: Thanks for your response! All the timeouts are set to 0 and is not working. Also it is a native MariaDB on AWS server.

Comment: @srgank have you changed default firewall settings in AWS? By default all ports are closed. You can verify it via `telnet <host> <port>` command

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, worked for me:

1. Open data source properties.
2. Go to Advanced tab.
3. Add to VM Options the following content including quotes:
   "-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, include jdk.disabled.namedCurves"
4. Apply and test connection.